# How to save classes and functions for universal usage in python

Tags: python, class, deep-learning, pip, static-libraries

I want save some classes and functions that I have wrote for Neural Networks, which I want to use in the future whenever I need them. Is there a way to save functions and classes in some library?

So more precisely, I'm looking for a library (let's call it tools), so that I can do:

```
save my_function in tool

...

from tool import my_function
```

Comment: Um. Presumably, you've already written your code. So it is unclear what you mean

Comment: Yes I have, and I am looking for a way to save the classes for future usage (basically it is the replay buffer, the DQN architecture and the agent).

Comment: Is have **no idea what you are asking then** and it would probably help for you to elaborate and clarify

Comment: read the comment below please, I have elaborated what I mean in more detail

Comment: You should edit your question and add the details there

Comment: Sorry but I don't feel like you are really interested in helping me. Apart from that, if you are not able to understand what I m looking for from the information I provided, I doubt you can help me anyways. It was apparently possible for others to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do that in Python is to simply save your functions in a separate python file (also called a module, see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)).

In your case the custom function code could be saved as the file tool.py.

You can then use the syntax you mentioned:

```
from tool import my_function
```

To import this specific function, **but** only if the file tool.py is actually in the same directory as the session you are importing it to (this is an easy way to add the module to your Module Search path, see the [offical documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)).

If you want to use the module in another directory, you can append the path where you saved tool.py to your sys.paths:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/dir/customcode/')
```

Then you can `from tool import my_function` in the same session, if you have tool.py saved in the directory `/usr/dir/customcode/`.

Comment: `sys.path.append('/usr/dir/customcode/')` is generally not the way to go about things... Note, the directory of the file that is being executed is actually irrelevant.

Comment: I can understand why it might not be ideal in the general case. In the personal context of the question it should be passable, or not? Any pointers/edits in the right direction are welcome, Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, thats almost what I am looking for. The only issue you also pointed out is, that I have to write these functions and classes that I want to save within a certain .py file. That is suboptimal to me, I would prefer to have the option, to have a library where I can add and delete functions whenever I need it, without actually modifying a python file. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Okay, I think I finally get what you are look for, at least partially. The main question that remains is where and when do you want to reuse those functions? In the code snippet you shared, it looks like you save and reuse the function in the same python script (which wouldn't really make sense). Is the problem that you do not have access to the code of `my_function`, or that you want to save a modified version of of some `base_function`? Otherwise, the straightforward way would be simply to use python modules i.e .py files

Comment: I want to reuse the replay buffer class for example every time I make a DQN. So every time I need it in the future, I want to write something like `from tool import Replay_Buffer`. It looks like a write that in the same python script, that was a mistake on my side.

Comment: Okay, your question does not really make that clear. Perhaps a more specific question like "How to store and reuse a Replay_Buffer class..." would give you better answers. A generic module that can be dynamically stored to doesn't exist afaik..

The class could have some basis in data that can be stored, but I am not sure if there is any interface for storing and reading this specific class in the packages you are using. At the very least you can pickle python objects, and reuse them in other scripts simply by reading from the pickle. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html